# Sorting big list in Python

Tags: python, sorting, large-files

I have a text file of 2 million lines whereby each line displays the coordinates and a value for potential at these coordinates e.g. `<x> <y> <z> value`. How should I go about reordering this file with a python script so that the data is sorted first by the `x` coordinate, then by the `y` coordinate and then by the  `z` coordinate.

Format:

```
1 2 1 value
1 8 6 value
4 3 2 value
```

etc ...

Desired Format:

```
1 1 1 value
2 1 1 value
3 1 1 value
```

etc..

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps consider the `pandas` package. But first try just loading and sorting it like normal as Mr_U4913 suggests. It'll probably take less time to run than developing a more efficient solution.

Comment: you are asking about reordering this file, 2 mil lines is not a Big list, you basically can do it in memory and the write the list back to file. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I like Python too, but the standard `sort` Linux/Unix command line utility is the perfect tool for this task.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  Do your searches before you ask.  "Python sort tutorial" should have kept you from having to type in your problem.

Comment: @VPfB valid point, but the OP may have no access to a Linux machine. You know, some people use Python on MS Windows.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Yes, it may be the case. I should have added something like _"Please let us know if this is an acceptable apporach for you"_ to my comment.

Comment: I am on a linux machine, how would I go about doing this with Linux sort?

Comment: @WillC `sort  -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 < infile >outfile` i.e. numeric sort with 3 keys: 1st, 2nd and 3rd field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file into a list and sort it, but it will take time because of the size. For example:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    data = sorted(f.readlines(), key=lambda x: int(''.join(x.split()[:3])))
```

If you want to remove the new line characters, use `f.read().splitlines()` instead.

Comment: You seem to have made an assumption that x, y, z are always 1-digit integers. This may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a key function:

```
the_list.sort(key=lambda line: tuple(map(int, line.split()[:3])))
```

(if your x, y, z coords are not integer, replace `int` with `float`)